# Swift: Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'xxx'

Tags: swift

I don't understand the meaning of this error. This is what I am trying to do:

```
protocol P {
    var testTitle: String? { get }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, P {
    var testTitle: String? {
        didSet {
            self.title = testTitle
        }
    }
}

final class TestViewController: MyViewController {
    var testTitle: String? { // Error occurs here
        return "Test" 
    }
}
```

And I'm getting:

> Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'testTitle'

Could you help me understanding what's going on? Maybe it's trivial for some people but not for me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol requires that the adopting class implements a property `testTitle` with a getter but it does **not** forbid to declare the property with getter **and** setter.

To override a property you have to override the (entire) signature in the class, not the protocol requirement.

As `testTitle` is declared as read/write you cannot override it as read-only.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is still one thing I don't understand, how am I declaring `testTitle` as read/write?

Comment: Apart from `didSet` – which is a property *observer*  not an accessor – the property is declared as **stored** property `String?` which is mutable by default.

Comment: You don't need the `return` statement in the getter if there's only a single line of code in the getter anymore, btw.

Answer (score 54):

You cannot implement a subclass to be more restrictive than the base class (it would only work the other way round). So if the base class implements a read/write property, you cannot make it read only in your derived class.

Therefore:

```
final class TestViewController: MyViewController {
    override var testTitle: String? { // No error occurs here 
        get {
            return "Test" 
        }
        set {
            super.testTitle = newValue
        }
    }
}
```